# SSRS Configuration

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to configure SSRS to use email subscription feature. This SSRS server is hosted on AWS and I have an SMTP relay to use. This SMTP relay requires an userid and password to authenticate.

I tried SSRS configuration manager and also the config file, but couldnt find how and where to use this user name and password for the relay.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with the configurations.

The same SMTP relay and account details are working fine when I'm trying to configure the Database email on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-a-report-server-for-e-mail-delivery-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2014

indicates that you can't use the GUI to set those additional parameters, but that you need to edit the file directly.

> (Optionally) Use a text editor to specify additional settings in the
>   RSreportserver.config file. This file contains all of the
>   configuration settings for Report Server e-mail delivery. Specifying
>   additional settings in these files is required if you are using a
>   local SMTP server or if you are restricting e-mail delivery to
>   specific hosts. For more information about finding and modifying
>   configuration files, see Modify a Reporting Services Configuration
>   File (RSreportserver.config) in SQL Server Books Online.

After a bit more digging around, I found a few articles that mention that it's just not possible.  One work-around is mentioned on this other Stack Exchange answer, where you are basically setting up IIS to be your own private relay service.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479550/how-to-use-gmail-account-for-ssrs-email-subscription

The quote below is from that answer, by BateTech.

> From what I have read, it sounds like you might have to setup a local
>   SMTP relay server that you send the email through, b/c SSRS requires
>   that "The Report Server service must have Send As permissions on the
>   SMTP server" and does not appear to give any options for entering a
>   password. I am assuming the SSRS subscription email setup only works
>   using Windows authentication since it uses the SSRS Service, but the
>   configuration documentation is vague.
>   (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345234(v=sql.105).aspx )
>
> Here is a link that shows how to setup the SMTP relay server
>   http://www.vsysad.com/2012/04/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2/
>
> Here are the steps you'll need to do differently.
>
> Item 19, choose Basic Authentication, enter your gmail account info,
>   and make sure TLS encryption is checked. Item 21, enter your server
>   name as the Fully-qualiified domain name. Enter "smtp.google.com" as
>   the "Smart host". Then specify the SMTP server you just created above
>   in your SSRS SMTP configuration.
>
> You probably also need to enable POP3 on your gmail account if you
>   have not already.
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13273?cbid=wl8yzeug2lob&src=cb&lev=topic

Comment: I tried that too but couldn't get to pass user id and password.